# Using CamelCase in a logo

Tags: logo, typography

I'm looking forward to getting a logo created for my company.

My partners and I have distinct views should we use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) in the logo or not. For example:

**boffr** vs **bOffr**

This made me wonder: when one should use CamelCase in a logo and when not?

Comment: is it readable? That's pretty much the main do/don't. (Do make it readable)

Comment: To be slightly more specific, does it read as you would like it to be read?

Comment: I think the placement of emphasis *may* depend upon the intent of the company, rather than the O. My gut here is telling me camel case is visually problematic because of the prevalence of ascenders, but you are pretty much locked in because that's the company name. In any event, when I see camel case, I think computers and when I see "bFoo", I expect Foo is a boolean value.

Comment: @lauren http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: @mlo55 welcome to the site! Rants disguised as a question are prohibited per our [FAQ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq) e.g. “______ sucks, am I right?” While you did ask for both dos and don'ts, I've neutralized the tone of your question even further, because I think it is reasonable and deserves not to be closed. +1.

Comment: I'm disappointed the Wikipedia article doesn't distinguish betwen CamelCase and dromedaryCase.

Comment: @e100 "For clarity, this article calls the two alternatives upper camel case and lower camel case.", and hey, it's a wiki so everyone can edit :-)

Comment: @horatio - it's the visual imbalance that puts me off the logo, my preference is to use a different foreground colour for the "b"... (to separate/emphasise it)... and, bOffer does remind me of a boolean :-)

Comment: Camel case doesn't start with an upper case letter but rather with a lower case so it would be correctyl **camelCase** and not CamelCase. The latter is called **PascalCase**

Comment: @Robert: not necessarily. Both forms have several names, both forms are often called camel case.

Comment: @e100: That's true, but this invalid naming has appeared lately. Pascal and Camel casing has been around since I can remember and they were very much distingushed in times of C. PascalCase for instance is invalidly calles as Capitalised camel case... That's just as if you call a bus *a car with 30+ seats*. Everything has a name for a reason. This is a bit extreme. I just wanted to point this out.

Answer (score 6):

In your example if you want the company name to be pronounced like "be offer", you probably want a space or camel-case or something.  "boffr" (to me) reads like "boffer"...  are you, by chance, [working in adult entertainment](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%20boffing)?  Tongue-in-cheek comment, to be sure, but an easy mistake to make if someone were to misread your logo.

At the end of the day, remember that you want your logo to instantly identify your company - you don't want it to be a word-game that distracts from the more important content you will be delivering.

Comment: I went the same way re: boffer. Another possibility is a deoderant BObeGone

Comment: This is the real question — not if the camelCase is pretty or not in a logo. iThink it can be powerful if used correctly.

Comment: How *do* you want it pronounced?

Comment: @e100, phonetically, it would be sounded as "boffer"...

Comment: it's not an adult site, but I like the cut of your jib :-)

Answer (score 4):

Camel case is used to distingush separate words, not make arbitrary capitals. So if those are separate words then camel case makes sense. In fact, I think you should capitalize both words; notice how this is StackExchange not stackExchange?

Although as others have pointed out you may want to rethink the entire name. Unless you're making a comedy website or something you may not want that word.

Comment: as I mentioned in a comment to the OP: the initial lower case is traditionally a computer programming signifier. So while you are correct about StackExchange, bOffr *might* be more appropriate

Comment: It's a taste thing. I don't like trendy Web 2.0 names like flickr or tumblr so I'm biased against the OP company's name anyway.

Comment: you are right about the capitalisation, I think BOffr makes more sense than bOffr, but they both seem visually imbalanced to me

Answer (score 1):

depends  on how you use camelcase in your logo,see there are thousand way to make a thing live,and your view cud be ugly for me and my view cud be ugly for you so create different styles for your logo and then decide which one looks good.

When it comes to camel case, it isn't actually the capital letters that are the issue. It's actually all about word spacing, or more specifically,someone in a room decided that camel case was cool, and the entire world just kind of ran with it. look **apple's iPhone** and **apple's iphone**  both are same but we know 1st one is right the way is different  we are seeing this from decade,so its kind of someone's perception of using camelCase rolling over the masses.At last Choice is yours to decide keep it simple or make it camel case.

**See this discussion**

http://www.osnews.com/story/22565/The_Rise_of_Camel_Case

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that matters in any logo is what you want to convey through the logo. If using camelCase conveys your message then so be it and moreover it is an internal matter between you and your partners. It doesn't matter what we think. :)

Comment: I disagree. The confusion here about how it actually should be pronounced demonstrates that it doesn't convey the intended message to external audience; at least not consistently.